# Algorithm for Trap Flag in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, x86-16

Is there any algorithm to set or clear TF? For example for ZF flag, we can making situation for set or clear it by adding two number that result is zero...

Answer (score 1):

The TF (Trap Flag) is not an arithmetic flag, it's a system/debug flag for single stepping. You can only manage it indirectly, for example through `POPF` or `IRET`.

Comment: The wikipedia article even has code for this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_flag

Comment: Are you sure he is really asking about `TF`?

Comment: Yes I'm sure he asked about trap flag !

Answer (score 0):

to enter the trap mode, use the  following code:

```
pushf
pop ax
or ah, 1
push ax
popf
```

This will set the 8th bit in the flag register, which defines, whether the trap mode is set or not.

to leave the trap mode, use the  following code:

```
pushf
pop ax
and ah, 11111110b
push ax
```

popf